# gems not showing in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I added some gem I wrote in my local `gem` repo (some `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems` path), but when I require it in my `RubyMine` project, it is not found and indeed it does not appear in my `RubyMine` loaded gems, and I can't find how to add it. How can I circumvent this ?

Comment: look at the /proc/<pid of ruby mine>/environ.  Is that path in $PATH?  If not, did you try restarting ruby mine?

Comment: @Davidann what do you mean by /proc/<pid of ruby mine>/environ

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked: are you using Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

There may be several things to try here - hard to tell what you have already done.

1. In RubyMine Tools > Bundler > Update
2. make sure you've got the gem in your Gemfile - either locally, or on a specific github repo...

   - gem 'mygemname', :path => '../myGem'
   - gem 'myGitGem', :git => 'git@github.com:MYREPOS/mygitgem.git'